# Jest css-modules SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, css-modules

I have set up my jest to allow static files after following their [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#mocking-css-modules) on how to do so, but I still recieve the following error.

How can I can it to pass and create a snapshot.

**Terminal Error**

```
FAIL  src/components/Splash/Splash.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /var/www/com/src/components/shared/logo/_Logo.css:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.logo {
                                                                                             ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

      3 | 
      4 | 
    > 5 | import logo from './_Logo.css';
      6 | import * as font from '../font/fontello.css';
```

**Splash.test.js**

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import Splash from './Splash';

it('Splash page is rendered', () => {
    const result = shallow(
        <Splash />,
    );

    expect(shallowToJson(result)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Jest Config**

```
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/app/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
        "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
      }
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
```

Comment: There seems to be an small mistake: `moduleNameMapper: {moduleNameMapper{}}` should just be `moduleNameMapper:{}`, also maybe running jest with `--no-cache` might help

Comment: Please add this as the answer andreas, sure its not really super helpful and rather bespoke, but it may help somebody else from not being so stupid :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small mistake: `moduleNameMapper: {moduleNameMapper{}}` should just be `moduleNameMapper:{}`

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
}
```

Comment: for me, installing identity-obj-proxy and "\\.(css)$": "jest-css-modules" worked

Answer (score 2):

It may work who use ***create-react-app*** from feb 2018.
I partially followed the docs [jest webpack](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack) to make it work.

Also found out the moduleNameMapper cannot be overriden in package.json but in jest.config.js it does the trick.
Unfortunately i havent found any docs about why it does but here is my answer.
Here is my ***jest.config.js***:

```
module.exports = {
...,
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(scss|sass|css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
}
```

and it skips scss files and @import quite well.

I added to devDependencies **identity-obj-proxy**